# How do I mathematically show that this equation diverges (and thus doesn't have a limit)?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Regarding the Limit:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} (\ln(1-x)-\sin x)/\sin^2x$$
when I sub in $x=0$ this formula is of the form $0/0$.

So I use L'hopital's rule which spits out:

$(-1/(1-x)-\cos x)/(2\cos x\sin x)$

Subbing in $x=0$ here results in$-2/0$ which I am to understand is
$-\infty$

however graphically I know this formula diverges, how do I prove this, mathematically?

Comment: What you have done shows that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Well, if something tends to infinity, then it diverges. This is a proof as good as any.

Comment: Your understanding of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\frac1{1-x}-\cos x}{2\cos x\sin x}$ is wrong, because clearly the limit as $x\to 0^+$ is $-\infty$ and the limit as $x\to 0^-$ is $\infty$. L'Hopital implies that the same two limits hold for the original.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick to solve the problem.

Since $x\to 0$ so $x\neq 0$ hence
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\ln (1-x)-\sin (x)}{\sin^2x} &=& \frac{\ln (1-x)-\sin (x)}{x^2}\times\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\\
&=& \frac{1}{x} \times \left(\frac{\ln (1-x)-\sin (x)}{x}\right)\times\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2.
\end{eqnarray}$$
When we take the limit $x\to 0$ we see that the second and the third term is bounded (since they converge to some finite number), and the only term that remains is the first term for which the limit diverges.

Comment: Thanks! I've corrected that.